# Django: Where is the best place to store uploaded file(pdfs, docs) that a user share on a django project?

Tags: django, file, django-models, file-upload, file-sharing

I am currently working on a Django project to make a file sharing website. I do aware that Django models cant save a file in their fields and only store a string that refers to it, and the file is saved in whatever folder i set in MEDIA_ROOT setting, which I find is not very secure and effective. So where do I store these uploaded files? Or is it safe enough to store it in the folder set by MEDIA_ROOT?

I can’t give any progress now as it is still all in my head and I have been searching too and the answer is nowhere to be found(or maybe i didnt try enough).

So what is the best practice to store these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your regards to `MEDIA_ROOT`, using it is fine, and you can add security if need be by modifying views/urls. However, in production, usually media files are served in the cloud, and you should write custom variables to manage these files.

You can choose different options, personally I use Amazon S3, where you can open a bucket and store all your files in there. When files are uploaded, they are stored there, and inside your model, you store the path inside the bucket there, and when you want to download it, you get your bucket root (i.e. www.amazon.com/s3/whatever) + the pathway you store inside your database.

This way instead of using `MEDIA_ROOT`, you use something like `AWS_PRIVATE_ROOT` or `AWS_PUBLIC_ROOT` and manage files there. With all of that said, the whole process is relatively similar, find somewhere to store the files, store them, add references to the file in your website later.

Best of luck, hope this helped.

Comment: whoa thank you very much, a whole new knowledge about using cloud for this. helped very much thanks again